# R - Adding a column that shows the days until today taking the data from dates

Tags: r, date, days

Using my dataset **listings** I am trying to create a separate column that shows the days until today (9. April, 2021) taking from a column indicating the days (host_since).
The column with the dates looks like this:

|  | host_since |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 19.01.10 |
| 2 | 09.03.10 |

(19.01.10 equals to 19. January 2010)

I am using R in RStudio.

Would really appreciate if someone could help me with this!

Comment: This needs so much clarification. Is it PHP? C#? SQL? If SQL, what flavor? (sql server, mysql, oracle)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please for a decent chance of your question getting qualified answers *edit it to state which tool and/or language you are using* and also *add the appropriate language tag* in addition to date and days (which are good and relevant). This is your chance to attract those who know to your question.

Comment: I am using R in RStudio.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Another thing that’s worth learning that doesn’t come natural: Add any new information in the question itself. You have an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67027989/edit) link under it for this purpose. It’s nice to have everything in one place, and R people won’t notice from a comment that here’s a question for them.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I am new to this but eager to learn :)

Comment: We’ve all been new here, and it does take a bit to learn how this site works and how to behave here. My own first questions were heavily downvoted. I hope you’ll find the site helpful.